# HTTP 403 while executing a PUT request

Tags: java, rest, csrf, httpurlconnection, http-put

I am creating a django rest api, and I'm trying to send JSON data via PUT request from an Android device, using HttpUrlConnection.

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
Log.v("Apiput", MainActivity.cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).toString());
conn.connect();
if(conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    return "" + conn.getResponseCode();
}
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
osw.write(put);
osw.flush();
osw.close();`
```

I know I have to send a csrf token, but I think that I'm sending it already.
By examining the META in my request I can see the csrf token both in headers and cookies:

`'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=3jLNzfLIu1P5dBH4WWwggHMH7oDQC7Rx;'`

And in my android device i have a CookieManager that says that the csrf cookie has the same value.

`V/Apiput﹕ csrftoken=3jLNzfLIu1P5dBH4WWwggHMH7oDQC7Rx`

I am getting a 403 (Forbidden) Http error besides the user is authenticated (I can make GET Requests)

`[26/Sep/2015 00:16:04]"PUT /api/works/34/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58`

With curl I am able to send the request without any problem, with the same user credentials.

I wonder if anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Try remove "; charset=UTF-8" from ContentType. I've had problems with DRF picking the correct parser when that is part of the ContentType.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the cookie if you're doing a JSON call to Django REST framework.
It would definitively help if you can provide the permissions associated to the view.

Comment: I have a ApiView with GET, PUT and POST methods, with isAuthenticated permission. I can access  the GET method, but can't access the PUT and POST. I even tried to change the permission to AllowAny, but still no luck.